# Why is this mongoose 'findOne' query always returning null?

Tags: javascript, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to find a specific document with mongoose in my Cosmosdb with this query described below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const Item = mongoose.model('items');

    const uploadToBlob = async (containerName, blobName, json, id) => {

        console.log('id', id)
        Item.findOne({ _id: id }, (foundItem) => {
            console.log(foundItem)
        });
        console.log('here')
        Item.findOneAndDelete({ name: blobName });
};
```

I am successfully able to find the document when querying like this below.

```
    const scanMongo = () => { 
    Item.find({
        _id: {
          $gt: ObjectID.createFromTime(Date.now() / keys.mongoPurgeInterval)
        }}, (err, foundItems) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log("Oops", err);
          return;
        }
        foundItems.forEach(item => {
            JSON.stringify(item)
            const blobName = item.name;
            json = "'"+item+"'"
            const id = item._id
            uploadToBlob(keys.containerName, blobName, json, id);
        });
    });
}
```

This is what the object I'm looking for looks like when pulled from the query above.

```
[ { _id: 5cabd5c6e16288230cba2cf6, name: 'test', value: 1, __v: 0 } ]
```

For kicks, here my model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const itemSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 value: Number,
});

mongoose.model('items', itemSchema);
```

I'm befuddled. Any help would be bawler. Thanks!!!

Comment: is the `id` in `uploadToBloban` function an  instance of `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`

Comment: Uhm. An instance? What do you mean?

uploadToBlob is a separate function from the second query. id is passed to it from the successful query that uses "Item.find({
        _id: {
          $gt: ObjectID.createFromTime(Date.now() / keys.mongoPurgeInterval)
        }}, (err, foundItems) => {".

Comment: you are trying to access an asynchronous variable outside of a callback that's why

Comment: Oh? You mean? Here? Item.findOne({ _id: id }, (foundItem) => {
            console.log(foundItem)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the first parameter is supposed to catch the error.

```
Item.findOne({ _id: id }, (error, foundItem) => {
            console.log(foundItem)
```